# how can i remove body , clone a div within the body and append it back

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use jQuery to remove the body of a page , but grab a div from that body and have it as the only one showing on the page

```
<body>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3">CLONE AND APPEND ME AS ONLY DIV TO SHOW IN BODY</div>
<div id="box4"></div>
</body>
```

I tried this , but didn't work. I'm certain i'd need to clone it first , and then replacewith ?

```
$('body').replaceWith('#box3');
```

Comment: What you are trying to do is `$('body').replaceWith($('#box3'));` ([DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/561nxy23/)), but why not `$('body div:not(#box3)').remove();` ([DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/561nxy23/1/))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```js
$('body').replaceWith($('#box3'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
<div id="box3">CLONE AND APPEND ME AS ONLY DIV TO SHOW IN BODY</div>
<div id="box4"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update

```
$('body').replaceWith('#box3');
```

to

```
$('body').replaceWith($('#box3').clone());
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/QNv6cdkGFzRXjOZ9XYPX?p=preview

Please see you were replacing it with text rather than html. Additionally, you could simply replace it with the element without cloning.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following...

```
$('div:not(#box3)').remove();
```